SVD of the projection of a matrix
Let $A\in\mathbb R^{d\times d}$ be a symmetric matrix whose SVD is $A = U \Lambda U^T$, where $U\in\mathbb R^{d\times d}$ is orthogonal and $\Lambda\in\mathbb R^{d\times d}$ is diagonal. Let $B\in\mathbb R^{d\times k}$ be an orthonormal matrix such that $B^TB=I_k$ with $k\le d$. Let $P = BB^T$ be the projection matrix onto the $k$-dimensional subspace. Then what is the explicit form of the SVD of the following matrix?
$$
P A P = V\Sigma V^T
$$
Here we still have $V\in\mathbb R^{d\times d}$ is orthogonal and $\Sigma\in\mathbb R^{d\times d}$ is diagonal. Note that $PAP$ has rank $k$. So $\Sigma$ only has $k$ non-zero values. I wonder if $V$ and $\Sigma$ can be written as functions of $U$, $\Lambda$, and $B$. Thank you!

It would be surprising if there is a closed form for $V$, $\Sigma$. But how about an algorithm that will not the SVD to $PAP$?
